# Where on Stack Exchange can ask questions about Software Quality Assurance or Software Architecture?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Are all Stack Exchange websites only there to ask about code related questions, or is there any website in the network where we can ask questions about other fields of software, like Quality Assurance, Architecture and Design and other questions related tp Software Engineering?

Comment: Related: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For software quality assurance, I suspect the best site would be [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com).  That is really about as exact a match as you can find.

Software quality assurance isn't *off* topic on Programmers.SE though you would likely find a better informed audience with specifically quality assurance concerns on their mind at SQA.SE.

When you get more into the design and engineering aspect of the process, Programmers.SE would likely be the choice.

Please do not cross post questions word for word between multiple sites.  Tailor them to the appropriate audience.  I'm not sure who is over at SQA.SE (I'm not an active member of that site), though Programmers.SE is mostly inhabited by programmers and they can have a different understanding of the question.  If you want to ask one group or the other, only ask that group.  If you want to ask both groups, ask it so that one is for people who are involved in testing and the other is for people who are involved in coding.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about the software development process and software engineering, including quality assurance, architecture & design are on topic at [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - software requirements
> - software architecture and design
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - development methodologies and processes
> - software engineering management
> - quality assurance and testing
> - software licensing